# Error on Flutter iOS: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, flutter, build, appdelegate

I am trying to build my Flutter app on `iOS` but I got this error:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

The error appear in `AppDelegate.swift` at class declaration.

I have no ideea why I got this error. Maybe someone could give my some advices to debug the problem.

Here is a screenshot with the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

select a **target** for your googleService-info.plist by opening file inspector and check [Runner] to true for your target

[image]